# How to use Ext5 combobox with data bindings

Tags: extjs, binding, combobox, store, extjs5

I want to use a combobox which receives the preselected value from a data binding and also the possible options from a data binding of the same store.
The panel items configuration looks like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'language_default',
    fieldLabel: 'Default Language',
    multiSelect: false,
    displayField: 'title',
    valueField: 'language_id',
    queryMode: 'local',
    bind: {
        value: '{database.language_default}',
        store: '{database.languages}'
    }
}
```

If I use this configuration, the store of the combobox is invalid and unuseable.

Is it possible to **bind** the *selected option* **and** also the *available options* of a **combobox**?

Comment: What exactly is "database.language_default" ? An id value or an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade to ExtJs 5.0.1 and you can use [selection binding](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/guides/whats_new/whats_new501.html#whats_new-_-whats_new501_-_selection_binding)

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'language_default',
    fieldLabel: 'Default Language',
    multiSelect: false,
    displayField: 'title',
    valueField: 'language_id',
    queryMode: 'local',
    bind: {
        value: '{database.language_id}',
        selection: '{database.language_default}',
        store: '{database.languages}'
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use this as soon as I can upgrade to ext 5.0.1. Thanks!